# Issues with keyIsDown() in p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to make a basic 2d game with p5js and p5.play. An issue that seems to cause issues every time I try to do anything is the keyIsDown function. Is there a way to determine if a key is down before pressing it? If I used

```
upKey = keyIsDown(UP_ARROW);
```

upKey will show as undefined until I press the up arrow. Is there any way to assign the respective boolean values to these types of things prior to pressing them?
As of now, my game will not properly work until I have pressed every involed key one time.

Comment: something like `upKey = keyIsDown(UP_ARROW) || false;` ?

Comment: @NickParsons Just tried this, That causes the variable to always be false.

Comment: can you possibly recreate your issue using the [p5js web editor](https://editor.p5js.org/) or create a code snippet?

Comment: @NickParsons Your solution actually did work I accidentally defined it in setup instead of draw. This seems to be a workaround for now. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, nice. You might not even need the `|| false` now that you have defined it in draw... (could be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

> The [keyIsDown()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyIsDown) function checks if the key is currently down, i.e. pressed. It can be used if you have an object that moves, and you want several keys to be able to affect its behaviour simultaneously, such as moving a sprite diagonally.

Note that the arrow keys will also cause pages to scroll so you may want to use other keys for your game.. but if you want to use arrow keys this is the code snippet from the reference page

```js
let x = 100;
let y = 100;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(512, 512);
}

function draw() {

  if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
    x -= 5;
  }

  if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
    x += 5;
  }

  if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) {
    y -= 5;
  }

  if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {
    y += 5;
  }

  clear();
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(x, y, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

To implement similar logic without the use of arrow keys you will need to determine the key code of the keys you want to use.

Here is an example that uses awsd keys and also logs out the key code of the currently pressed key.

```js
let x = 50;
let y = 50;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(512, 512);
}
function keyPressed(){
console.log(keyCode);
}

function draw() {
  if (keyIsDown(65)) {
    x -= 5;
    if (x < 0) x = 0;
  }

  if (keyIsDown(68)) {
    x += 5;
    if (x > width) x = width;
  }

  if (keyIsDown(87)) {
    y -= 5;
    if (y < 0) y = 0;
  }

  if (keyIsDown(83)) {
    y += 5;
    if ( y > height) y = height;
  }

  clear();
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(x, y, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```