# How to move square with keys in javascript?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm a beginner programmer literally trying to code for the first time after watching some Coding Train videos and I am simply trying to move a square around the screen using the keys.

I have what I thought is the right way to do it up oversimplified like `y = y + 20;` instead of `y += 20;` but it still won't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var y = 200;
var x = 200;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  rect(x, y, 20, 20);
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    y = y + 10;
    console.log("help")
  } else {
      return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.3.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: paste code instead of image.And add `draw()` next line of `y=y+20`

Comment: I thought I did post the code and when you say next to again I have no idea what I'm doing so could explain more?

Comment: i m not familer with p5.js.just call the `draw()` function inside the keypress the after `y` value updated.It will redraw the position of rectangle

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54811918/1978785 It has some extra information about responding to key strokes

Answer (score 3):

You should get into the habit of looking at your [developer tools](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) for errors. You'll see that you're getting an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: keycode is not defined (sketch: line 14)
```

If you consult [the P5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/) you'll see that it should be `keyCode` instead of `keycode`.

But even if you fix that, you're going to have another problem.

Your best friend is [the P5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyCode) which explains:

> The variable keyCode is used to detect special keys such as BACKSPACE, DELETE, ENTER, RETURN, TAB, ESCAPE, SHIFT, CONTROL, OPTION, ALT, UP_ARROW, DOWN_ARROW, LEFT_ARROW, RIGHT_ARROW.

You could figure out what the code is for the <kbd>W</kbd> key, but it's probably easier to just use the `key` variable instead.

Also note that because you're checking against `'W'` you'll have to hold in shift to type an upper-case letter. You might consider using `'w'` instead.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js) are some tutorial on P5.js.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I fixed my mistakes but still, nothing happens. I'll update the code after I'm done typing this.

Comment: Could it be that I am doing this on the web editor instead of the running from the separate tab thing like Daniel does in coding train.

Comment: @JaggerDenhof I'm using the web editor as well. Maybe make sure the canvas is focused by clicking on it before typing any letters? Also try debugging your code: maybe add extra print statements to understand better what's going on?

Comment: lol i literally had to click the screen. I'm dumb. Thx a lot.